# Jagged Array initialization in C# with a default value

Tags: c#, arrays, ssl-certificate, integration

```
Signature[][][][] signature = ?
```

**Update:**

Its not multidimensional array it is a JaggedArray

Comment: my scenario is very different please look it care...

Comment: As an aside, anything which works for *two* dimensions is likely to work for four as well - and be a lot simpler to give examples of. Your question needs a lot more explanation though, along with what you've tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "multidimensional array" but in your example you have a "jagged array" which you can initialize like this:

```
int[][][] jaggedArray = new int[][][]
{
    new int[][] {new int[] {1,3,5,7,9} },
    new int[][] {new int[] {1,3,5,7,9} }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The array in c# have to be declared like
    string[,,] Arr=new string[1,3,5];
where 1,3,5 are the lengths of the 3D array..

You don't have to use string[][][].